# Select 10 row upper and lower from selected row

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm having SQL Select like that

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` = '2'
```

I'm selecting that from "Players rank".And i want to show 10 upper and lower from hem,so player can see hes enemyes,to know how much more he need to beat them.So i need to select 10 upper and lower rows from selected.How can i do that?

Comment: `ORDER BY yourCol LIMIT 10` and then `UNION` with the same query except using `ORDER BY yourCol DESC`.

Comment: What does "foo" have to do with "Players rank"?  How do you know the points for anyone?  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, Data is Score and ID,where ID - ID of player.Bigger score - better rank ;)